# 403 Access Not Configured Google Api youtube

Tags: android, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to authenticate and upload videos to youtube from my app. Refering to   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert for the same.

However when I try to do run my android app I consistently get the 403 Access Not Configured error message. When attempting to try the api from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert , the error I see is  "code": 403,"message": "Quota Exceeded".

My app is an android app which used the account manager to fetch an auth token from the account manager and use the same for the upload.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you parse the valid access_token?

Comment: Yes, I was able to view my auth token.

Comment: Update:I eventually used the resumable upload mechanism to upload my video's.However the same error was seen here.Using an api key for the android app did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used the resumable upload mechanism to upload my video's.However the same error was seen here.Using an api key for the android app did the trick. The Simple api key can be created in one's google api console, with the specific app's sha1/package name updated or the key can be used for any android app.With the api key mentioned, my url looks like [this](https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=PARTS&key=API_KEY). Let me know if any qn's/comments. I am still figuring out why the need for an api key when the auth token is already available.

Comment: I am trying to receive an access token by providing client_id,redirect_uri,scope,response_type=token after authorizing the application it shows (403) Access Not Configured error, although I am using normal API key not android one. do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have the scope and the url for the service correctly defined?

Comment: It seems everything is correct but it runs into an error my question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872701/i-can-not-receive-access-token-from-google-api-and-upload-video-on-youtube/16884844?noredirect=1#comment24427349_16884844